# Derivative of product of vector valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable.
> For $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we define the functions
>
> - $\xi:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}: t\mapsto \xi(t):=x+ty$ and
> - $\rho: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:t\mapsto \rho(t):=f(\xi(t))$.
>
> I need to prove that
>
> 1. $\rho'(t)=\nabla f(\xi(t))y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))y_{i}$ and
> 2. $\rho''(t)=y^{T}H_{f}(\xi(t))y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}(\xi(t))y_{i}y_{j}$
>    holds.
>
> Note: The gradient of a function is defined as a row vector.

The first part follows from the chain rule.
$$\rho'(t)
=
\frac{d}{d t} f(\xi(t))
=
f'(\xi(t))\xi'(t)
=
\nabla f(\xi(t))\xi'(t)
=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))y_{i}
$$
where I've used
$
\nabla f(\xi(t))
=
\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(\xi(t))
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}(\xi(t))
\ldots
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}(\xi(t))  \right)
$
and
$\xi'(t)=y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ for the last step.

Using $\rho'(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))y_{i}$, the second part follows via

$$
\begin{align}
\rho''(t)
=
(\rho'(t))'
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))y_{i}\right)\\
&=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))y_{i}\right)\\
&=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left( \nabla \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))\xi'(t)\right)y_{i} \\
&=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{j}\partial x_{i}}(\xi(t))y_{i}y_{j} \\
&=
y^{T}H_{f}(\xi(t))y
\end{align}
$$.

However I was not able to find a direct way starting from $\rho'(t)=\nabla f(\xi(t))y$ to show the second part. My first attempt looks as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\rho''(t)
=
(\nabla f(\xi(t))\xi'(t))'
=
(\nabla f(\xi(t)))'\xi'(t)+(\nabla f(\xi(t)))\xi''(t)
\end{align}
$$
Since $\xi''(t)=0$ the last term disappears leaving me with

$$
\begin{align}
\rho''(t)
=
(\nabla f(\xi(t)))'\xi'(t)
=
(\nabla f(\xi(t)))'\xi'(t)
= 
J(\nabla f(\xi(t))\xi'(t)\xi'(t)
=H_{f}(\xi(t))\xi'(t)\xi'(t)
\end{align}
$$
Which is not exactly what I'm looking for (and is wrong since the dimensions for matrix multiplication do not match). However since $H_{f}=J(\nabla f)$ is symmetric, it seems that it would be sufficient if $(\nabla f(\xi(t)))'=\xi'(t)^{T}J(\nabla f(\xi(t)))$.

The problem is that I do not know why this should be the case.

**Update:** 
Inspired by Steph I found this [reference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Dot_Product_of_Vector-Valued_Functions) which inspired be to the following proof.
Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\langle x,y\rangle=x^{T}y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}$ (scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). Then
$$
\frac{d}{d t}\langle f(t),g(t) \rangle
=
\left\langle \frac{d}{dt} f(t),g(t) \right\rangle+\left\langle \frac{d}{dt} g(t),f(t) \right\rangle
=
\left\langle J(f)(t),g(t) \right\rangle+\left\langle J(g)(t),f(t) \right\rangle
$$
Proof:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d t}\langle f(t),g(t) \rangle
&=
\frac{d}{d t}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(t)g_{i}(t)\\
&=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{d}{d t}(f_{i}(t)g_{i}(t))\\
&=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f'_{i}(t)g_{i}(t)+f_{i}(t)g'_{i}(t)\\
&=\langle J(f)(t),g(t) \rangle+\langle J (g)(t),f(t) \rangle
\end{align}
$$
Where $J$ is the Jacobian given by $J(f)=\left(\frac{df_{1}}{dt} \ldots \frac{df_{n}}{dt} \right)$

Using this I get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d t}\rho'(t)
&=
\frac{d}{d t}\left\langle \nabla f(\xi(t)), \xi'(t)\right\rangle\\
&=
\left\langle \frac{d}{d t} \nabla f(\xi(t)), \xi'(t)\right\rangle+\left\langle J (\xi')(t), f(\xi(t))\right\rangle\\
&=
\left\langle J(\nabla f)(\xi(t))\xi'(t), \xi'(t)\right\rangle+0\\
&=
(J(\nabla f)(\xi(t))\xi'(t))^{T} \xi'(t)\\
&=
\xi'(t)^{T}H_{f}(\xi(t))\xi'(t)\\
\end{align}
$$.
In the last step I've used that $H_{f}(t)=J(\nabla f)^{T}$.

Comment: $(D f\circ\xi)'=\left((D f)'\circ\xi\right)\xi'=\left((D^2f)\circ\xi\right)(y,\cdot)$ hence $\rho''=\left((D^2f)\circ\xi\right)(y,y).$ And $D^2f(a)(u,v)=u^TH_f(a)v.$

Comment: What is $J$ in your computation?

Comment: @Gribouillis $J$ is the Jacobian.

Comment: @AnneBauval Why is $D^{2}f(a)(u,v)=u^{T}H_{f}(a)v$?

Comment: Because $D^2f(a)(u,v)=\sum \partial^2_{i,j}f(a)u_iv_j.$

Comment: @bayes2021 "Jacobian" is only a word. I think you need to explain what you mean exactly with the equality $H_f = J(\nabla f)$ and also $(\nabla(f(\xi)))' = J(\nabla f(\xi))\xi'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the derivative $\rho'(t)=\nabla_f(\xi):\mathbf{y}$
where the colon denotes the inner product between vectors.

Taking the differential yields
$$
d\rho'
=\mathbf{H}_f(\xi) d\xi:\mathbf{y}
=\mathbf{H}_f(\xi) \mathbf{y}:\mathbf{y} dt
$$
so it holds
$$
\rho''(t)
=\mathbf{H}_f(\xi) \mathbf{y}:\mathbf{y}
=\mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{H}_f(\xi) \mathbf{y}
$$
which is basically what you have done avoiding indices...

Comment: Could you explain why this holds? Or cite a reference? I have the feeling I need mote context why this holds.

Comment: I simply used the fact the relation between a gradient and its Hessian $d\nabla_f=\mathbf{H}_f d\xi$ nothing more really!

Comment: That is clear. I was thinking about the differential of the inner product. But I found a reference myself.